# NSString format string with number of repetitions

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

**Code:**

```
[mutableExpectedContent appendFormat:@"%@%@%@",
 expectedSuffix ?: @"",
 PILLoremIpsum,
 PILParagraphBreak];
```

**Question:**

Is it possible to substitute repeated arguments of the same type like `%@%@%@` for something simpler? I'd love to use a quantifier that describes number of repetitions; like `%3@` or similar. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

No, here is an [article](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1) that summarises the format specifiers supported by string formatting methods and functions.